# Proof of an equivalence about powers of $2$ and divisors

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found this equivalence:

> For all natural numbers $n > 1$,
>   $\exists k\in\mathbf N, n=2^k \iff \neg (\exists p\in\mathbf Z, (2p+1)\ne\pm 1 \wedge (2p+1)\mid n)$

in my textbook. The proof has been omitted. I will like to see the proof and run through it myself. I have tried to search on the web but could not find any.

P.-S. I have translated the equivalence into English from the original language.

Comment: Do you mean $\exists k\in\mathbb N:n=2^k$?

Answer (score 1):

This is just not true. Take e.g. $n=6$.

$ n = 6 = 2 . 3$  but $n$ has an odd divisor other than $+1$ and $-1$.
This divisor is 3.

Probably in the statement should have been written $∃k \in N,n=2^k$ instead of $n=2k$.

Almost certainly it's a typo, that typo.

Proof:

1) If $n$ has no odd divisor other than $+1$ and $-1$, then n has no prime odd divisor. Then since n>1, it means that only the prime $2$ divides $n$. So the left side follows.

2) If $n=2^k$ then obviously it has no odd prime factor. So it cannot have an odd divisor other than $+1$ and $-1$.

All in all, this is too obvious if you have already studied *the fundamental theorem of arithmetic*.

Now... I don't know if you know that theorem or not. I used it in this proof (in fact it makes the proof trivial).

Maybe you're looking for a proof which does not use that theorem, not sure.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

*Proof.*

- Let $n\in \mathbf N$ such as $n=2^k, k\in \mathbf N$. By the uniqueness of the factorization into prime numbers, any divisor of $n$ is written as $\pm2^p, p\leq k$. If $p=0$, we obtain a trivial divisor (excluded in the equivalence). Else, we obtain an even number.
- We assume that no odd number divides $n\in \mathbf N$. The decomposition into prime numbers involves only the even prime number (i.e. $2$). $n=2\times \dots\times 2=2^k, k\in\mathbf N$.

Q.e.d.

Answer (score -1):

Some one has edited the equivalence.
A moderator maybe? I find this very odd and I'm not sure what to do.
The original equivalence was

$\exists k\in\Bbb N: n=2^k\iff\neg(n\text{ has other odd divisors than}\pm 1)$